# Testing POST with authentication in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to test POSTing data to a view in `django-rest-framework` that requires authentication. But I can't. I've read many threads of supposed solutions, but can't find any that solves to me.

Serializer:

```
class ResearcherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    studies = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Study.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Researcher
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'surname', 'email', 'studies')
```

View:

```
class ResearcherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    studies = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Study.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Researcher
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'surname', 'email', 'studies')
```

Test:

```
class ResearcherAPITest(APITestCase):
    base_url = reverse('api_researchers')
# ...

def test_POSTing_a_new_researcher(self):
    user = User.objects.create(username='lab1', password='nep-lab1')
    self.client.login(username=user.username, password=user.password)
    response = self.client.post(
        self.base_url,
        {
            'first_name': 'João',
            'surname': 'das Rosas',
        }
    )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    new_researcher = Researcher.objects.first()
    self.assertEqual(new_researcher.first_name, 'João')
    self.client.logout()
```

I receive this error:

```
FAIL: test_POSTing_a_new_researcher (experiments.tests.test_api.ResearcherAPITest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/caco/Workspace/nep-system/nep/experiments/tests/test_api.py", line 130, in test_POSTing_a_new_researcher
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
AssertionError: 403 != 201

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Had read `drf` Testing documentation but can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right way to create a user is using `User.objects.create_user()` as teach  [official Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#creating-users). When using `create_user()` method the password parameter is hashed before saving in database, while common `create()` method does not do that.

Also, it's necessary login with

```
self.client.login(username=user.username, password='nep-lab1')
```

instead `user.password` as `password` parameter in `APIClient.client.login()` method, as pointed out by @oz-main.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can't access to `user.password` as you are trying to. Also, I'd give some advices:

- Since you're using `APITestCase`. Try to use setUp method to create your user in database. That way you will be able to re-use that user in other cases
- Follow pep8 guidelines to write your code.`test_POSTing_a_new_researcher` is a very weird method name
- Take a look at [factory boy](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/), it might make your life easier by replacing the fixture approach

Good resource for testing: http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tips man. I verified here and user.password is accessible. By the way, I'm learning Django TDD with http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/, a great resource. But there is a quick Appendix covering testing API and `django-rest-framework` in particular. No authentication tests. Anyhow thanks for help me.

Answer (score 1):

base on the test case you've written
the test user is not logged in because you are trying to log in a user using the hashed password and not the `nep-lab1`. you can test if you've successfully logged in by:

```
print self.client.login(username=user.username, password=`nep-lab1`)
# True if logged in and False if not
```

and since the user is not logged your test on posting a new researcher via api would result to `FORBIDDEN`(403) http response and not `CREATED`(201)

Comment: In fact, printing `user.password` gives 'nep-lab1'. I discovered here that the correct way of creating user is with [User.objects.create_user()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#creating-users) and not `User.objects.create()` like common model classes. The first method hashes the password for us. Anyhow thanks for replying.  You've open my mind to that error.